# Unique values between multiple views on same page

Tags: views

I have a page that has several views on it.  I would like the views to show unique values.

For example, let's say I have a view that shows a few teasers for a content type.  This view has four displays, each with unique filter criteria.  But, the filter criteria may result in the same node being found in multiple displays:

- Display 1: nids = 1, 2, 3, 4
- Display 2: nids = 1, 3, 5, 7
- Display 3: nids = 2, 4, 6, 8
- Display 4: nids = 3, 6, 9, 12

I would like to eliminate the duplicates before the limiting occurs:

- Display 1: nids = 1, 2, 3, 4
- Display 2: nids = 5, 7, 9, 11
- Display 3: nids = 6, 8, 10, 12
- Display 4: nids = 15, 18, 21, 24

Is this possible?

Comment: I would love to see a better solution that the one I answered with.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [`hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7), and manually invoke a view, and then add an additional filter with [`$view->add_where()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3a%3aadd_where/7):, eg:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if (request_path() == 'some/path' && $view->name == 'myview') {
    $nids = array();

    $view1 = views_get_view('myview');

    if ($view->current_display == 'mydisplay2') {
      $view1->preview('mydisplay1');
    }
    else if ($view->current_display == 'mydisplay3') {
      $view1->preview('mydisplay2');
    }
    else if ($view->current_display == 'mydisplay4') {
      $view1->preview('mydisplay3');
    }

    if (!empty($view1->result)) {
      foreach ($view1->result as $index => $result) {
        $nids[] = $result->nid;
      }
    }

    if (!empty($nids)) {
      $query->add_where(0, 'node.nid', $nids, 'NOT IN');
    }
  }
}
```

The order of the if/else checking should be the same as the order of the views on your page.